# Prim's Algorithm on Vector<Vector<int>> Resulting In SegFault

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, prims-algorithm

I have the following 3 functions:

```
int minKey(vector<int> key, vector<bool> mstSet){
    int min = INT_MAX;
    int min_index;
    for (int i = 0; i<elements2D.size(); i++){
        if (mstSet[i] == false && key[i] < min){
            min = key[i];
            min_index = i;
        }
    }
    return min_index;
}

int printMST(vector<int> parent, int n, vector<vector<int>> graph){
    cout << "edges: " << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i<graph.size(); i++){
        cout << parent[i] << " " << i << endl;
    }
}

void primMST(vector<vector<int>> graph){
    vector<int> parent;
    parent.reserve(graph.size());
    vector<int> key;
    key.reserve(graph.size());
    vector<bool> mstSet;
    mstSet.reserve(graph.size());

    for (int i = 0; i<graph.size(); i++){
        key[i] = INT_MAX;
        mstSet[i] = false;  
    }

    key[0] = 0;
    parent[0] = -1;

    for (int count = 0; count<graph.size()-1; count++){
        int u = minKey(key, mstSet);
        mstSet[u] = true;
        for (int v = 0; v < graph.size(); v++){
            if (graph[u][v] && mstSet[v] == false && graph[u][v] < key[v]){
                parent[v] = u;
                key[v] = graph[u][v];
            }
        }
    }
    printMST(parent, graph.size(), graph);  
}
```

And in my main function, I call it like this:

```
primMST(elements2D); //elements2D is my adjacency matrix
```

However, it constantly returns a segmentation fault. By the use of debugging, I have pinpointed where this happens, but I am not sure how to remedy the situation.

So basically, I figured out that when I say:

```
int u = minKey(key, mstSet)
```

it results in the segfault. So I followed it into the function and I have discovered that key[i] is not working. Something about it keeps outputting my result as a segfault. If anyone could help me fix this that would be much appreciated.

Some important information:

elements2D looks like this:

```
0 2 6 0 0 0 0 3
2 0 0 0 4 0 0 1
6 0 0 0 3 0 0 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 4 3 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0
0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0
3 1 2 0 0 0 0 0
```

The output should look like this:

```
edges:
0 1
1 7
2 7
2 4
5 6
```

I guess it is important to note that my code is trying to find the edges of the minimum spanning tree in a graph using Prim's algorithm.

Comment: Are you sure you nowhere accessing these vectors out of bounds? Please start your code in the debugger and check the indices at each step.

Comment: Read this [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What does `vector::reserve()` do?  Checking to see if you read the docs for that function carefully.

Answer (score 1):

```
int minKey(vector<int> key, vector<bool> mstSet){
    int minKey(vector<int> key, vector<bool> mstSet){
    int min = INT_MAX;
    int min_index; // NOT INITIALIZED!
    for (int i = 0; i<elements2D.size(); i++){ // What is elements2D?
        if (mstSet[i] == false && key[i] < min){ // What if the two vectors are different sizes?
            min = key[i];
            min_index = i;
        }
    }
    return min_index;
}
```

I see several problems in the function. `min_index` is never initialized; if the for loop runs no times, what is returned? Also, where is `elements2D` defined? You seem to be iterating over `key` and `mstSet`. Make sure that their sizes are the same, or better yet, use `std::vector<std::pair<int, bool>>`.

The subscript operator of `std::vector` does not perform bounds checking. Use `at` for more safety.

Comment: I set min_index to INT_MAX as well. In my primMST function, I run a for loop initializing key and mstSet to have the same size. I also reserve the same amount of space in both of them. And for elements2D, it is my adjacency matrix, I am reading a graph from it.

Comment: It's better practice to pass `elements2D` into the function as a parameter instead of using some global variable.

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is that you're using [std::vector::reserve()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) instead of [std::vector::resize()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize).

This section of code accesses the vector's with an out-of-bounds index, since `reserve()` does not create the elements.

```
void primMST(vector<vector<int>> graph){
    vector<int> parent;
    parent.reserve(graph.size());
    vector<int> key;
    key.reserve(graph.size());
    vector<bool> mstSet;
    mstSet.reserve(graph.size());

    for (int i = 0; i<graph.size(); i++){
        key[i] = INT_MAX;  // <-- out of bounds access
        mstSet[i] = false;  // <-- out of bounds access
    }
```

The fix is to use either `std::resize()`, as that actually creates the entries in the vector, or construct the vector with the requisite size.

```
void primMST(vector<vector<int>> graph){
    vector<int> parent(graph.size());
    vector<int> key(graph.size(), INT_MAX);
    vector<bool> mstSet(graph.size());
```

The subsequent `for` loop is not necessary, since the constructor for `key` and `mstSet` initializes the vector with the values specified in the second parameter of the constructor (or in the case of `vector<bool>`, the values are set to `false`).